# how to handle duplicated place listings in HERE search API

Tags: geocoding, here-api, autosuggest

**NOTE**: this question is specifically for support staff of the HERE Developer API because they ask freemium users to post support questions on Stack Overflow rather than trying to contact them directly. If you're not a member of their staff and you're unable to help or if the question is unclear to you, don't worry about it. :)

---

How can I handle duplicated listings returned by the search endpoints? I use both `/autosuggest` and `/discover` and I've noticed that some businesses are duplicated with very slight differences in their properties except for their IDs. However in the HERE mobile app, those duplicates don't show up. Specific examples are:

- Pizza 24: the IDs of the duplicates we've seen are `here:pds:place:8409q5c3-5b06808fd3b838ae0660eb1d8085822f` and `here:pds:place:8409q5c3-0d53d37882a748c2aaa58782989b63e5`
- Lenzini's Pizza: the IDs of the duplicates we've seen are `here:pds:place:8409q5c3-d0bbc81a1b199188ff9194b6ab093ac1` and `here:pds:place:8403fv6k-3f99756021610424619424385003db58`. The screenshot below from the HERE mobile app shows that all the displayed results are unique places, but these duplicates are for the place at `12740 Culver Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90066, United States` (second place in the screenshot)
  [image: duplicated-lenzinis-pizza]
- Manhattan Pizzeria: the IDs of the duplicates we've seen are `here:pds:place:8409q5bc-16fff9dec3584963a0361aaada0af8c6` and `here:pds:place:840jx7ps-ad85328ee4230ae0ea9a64aad3b5af4c`

It's clear that there's a way that the HERE team gets around this problem, so I'd like to replicate that for myself if possible. Thanks! :)

Comment: What about a last edited/updated timestamp? Curious how HERE themselves are handling.

Comment: did you solve this issue? There are hundred of thousand of duplicates in Here places

Answer (score 1):

Actually #9 On this URL (and a few other fixes) state duplicates

#9 Query for "International Tap House" returns duplicates.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/release_notes/topics/resolved-issues.html

However nothing is stating how to fix as per this scenario which is on-the-fly. Where 2 places are same (duplicate) in almost all ways, same address etc but have unique IDs and maybe a slight difference in hrs of operation or something. HERE own all doesn't show both as shown above so there must be a logic mechanism to filter one out (or a best practices suggestion).